# problem in phpBB3 login system integration

Tags: phpbb3

i am going to integrate phpBB registration system with my own site reg system..
here is the code

```
<?php
require_once("includes/functions.php");


$last_id = $_GET['id'];
$usr = decrypt($_GET['variable1']);
$passwd = decrypt($_GET['variable2']);
$em = decrypt($_GET['variable3']);

//echo 'last id: '.$last_id.' usr: '.$usr.' passwd: '.$passwd.' em: '.$em;
//exit();


define('IN_PHPBB', true);
/* set scope for variables required later */
global $phpbb_root_path;
global $phpEx;
global $db;
global $config;
global $user;
global $auth;
global $cache;
global $template;

# your php extension
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
$phpbb_root_path = 'forum/';

/* includes all the libraries etc. required */
require($phpbb_root_path ."common.php");
//$user->session_begin();
//$auth->acl($user->data);

/* the file with the actual goodies */
require($phpbb_root_path ."includes/functions_user.php");

/* All the user data (I think you can set other database fields aswell, these seem to be required )*/

$user_row = array(
'username' => $usr,
'user_password' => md5($passwd),
'user_email' => $em,
'group_id' => 2/*$default_group_id*/,
'user_timezone' => '5.00',
'user_dst' => 0,
'user_lang' => 'en',
'user_type' => '0',
'user_actkey' => "",
'user_dateformat' => 'd M Y H:i',
'user_style' => '',
'user_regdate' => time(),
);

/* Now Register user */
$phpbb_user_id = user_add($user_row);
if(!empty($phpbb_user_id)) {
    echo 'success';
    //redirect_to("register_status.php?id={$last_id}");
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
```

the error is The file utf_normalizer.php could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing from the error that you've copied phpBB's functions.php to another part of the site? That won't work because it is linked to several other files in the includes path. For example, utf_normalizer.php is used during login to clean any non-English characters our of the username for easier comparison.

Check the [Sessions Integration](http://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/phpbb3-sessions-integration/) page out over at phpbb.com for an already working solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer actually I just copied the code in my own site. I have done this by using this code afterall